# Is it possible to work GET and post option together in form?

Tags: php, html

I have a form in my site. I wanna add GET and post option together. Which will indicate 2 different destination.
Example : -
when someone submit a form ( name and address ) then he can enter a restricted section.
Then code will be

```
<form name="loginform"
action="http://site.com/viparea"
method="post">
```

And beside this i wanna keep a log.And for the log code is

```
<form name="loginform"
action="logcode.php"
method="GET">
```

And encrypted log will be save in a text file.

I have used two methods individually . And those are working fine individually.
But i wanna make them work together.
So, i am not a coder but after searching something i just did a simple work like a noob :P .

```
<form name="loginform"
action="http://site.com/viparea"
method="post"><form name="loginform"
action="logcode.php"
method="GET">
```

But not working. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Not seeing any code in question...

Comment: You cannot nest `<form>` elements inside each other. Either use AJAX to make the second post, or update the first submit handling script to perform the logging as well as its real task.

Comment: First off, DCoder is correct, you can not nest form elements inside each other.  So in order to do what you want you will have to use javascript or some really fancy coding.

If your backend is in PHP, why not just use $_REQUEST?

Comment: form tag inside a form tag is not supported :D

Answer (score 6):

You can only achieve this by using:

```
<form name="loginform" action="http://site.com/viparea?var1=var&var2=var" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="var3" />
</form>
```

this way you will get `var1` and `var2` as `$_GET`, `var3` as `$_POST` OR all 3 vars as `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @MihaiLorga  
Nice, gotten a nice solution from that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't; but in php you can use [$_REQUEST[]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), to see data from both GET and POST; you may need just a little changes in your php code.